# get all the non nan values of a pandas column

Tags: pandas, filter, nan

imagine I have a DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country':['UK','UK','UK','UK','US','US','US','US','US','US'],
                         'result':[np.nan,'A','B',np.nan,np.nan,'C','D',np.nan,4,np.nan]})
```

I would like to get all the result column values different than np.nan for a given country.

I dont understand why this does not work:

```
country= 'UK'
mask_country = df['country'] == country
mask_result   = df['result'].notnull()

# does not work
df.loc[mask_country & mask_result,[country]]
# does not work:
df.loc[mask_country & mask_result,country]
```

some idea?

expected result
['A','B'] for UK
and
['C','D',4] for US

EDIT:
Actually another way to filter is "give me all the values being str not being '' or spaces.

Comment: `df.loc[df['country'].eq('UK') & df['result'].notnull(), 'result']`?

Comment: t = df[df['country'] == 'UK']['result'].dropna().to_list()
--> ['A', 'B']

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)+[`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to get all the non null values for all countries at once as a Series

```
s = (df.dropna(subset=['result'])
       .groupby('country')['result']
       .agg(list)
     )
```

output:

```
>>> s
country
UK       [A, B]
US    [C, D, 4]

>>> s['UK']
['A', 'B']
```